# PySpark Exploding Key by Value and Preserve Duplicates for LDA Model

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, lda

I have an RDD of tuples. I want to explode key value pairs and preserve duplicates. Essentially key x value. I want to feed this RDD of arrays into an LDA model. I'll illustrate some code below, thank you in advance:

## Current State

```
>>> rdd4.take(2)
[ [(u'11394071', 1), (u'11052103', 1), (u'11052101', 1)],
[(u'11847272', 2), (u'999999', 1), (u'11847272', 3)] ]
```

## Preferred State

```
>>> rdd4.take(2)
[ ['11394071','11052103','11052101'],
['11847272', '11847272','999999','11847272','11847272','11847272'] ]
```

Comment: I tried the below answer and that doesn't work for what I need. I've also looked into pyspark sql for exploding. I originally thought a flatmap would work but I'm struggling to get it to do the key * value. So if value = x[1] and count = x[2] how I get those to iterate through and provide a value * count and keep the duplicates. Sorry if my terminology is bad I'm super new to Python and Spark.

Comment: I'm trying to set the data up to feed into an LDA model shown here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution without using list comprehension, probably more clear:

```
import itertools

orig_list = rdd4.take(2)

result = []
for orig_list_item in orig_list:
    inner_result = []
    for item, count in orig_list_item:
        inner_result.append([item] * count)
    inner_result = itertools.chain.from_iterable(inner_result)
    inner_result = list(inner_result)
    result.append(inner_result)
```

The explanation is in effect the same as in my other answer.

Comment: when I try and apply this to the entire rdd4 i get the error: TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable. Other than that it works on the 2 records but not the entire rdd.

Comment: I just did an rdd4.count() and got 2887. Then I did orig_list = orig_list = rdd4.take(2887) and it worked. Any help with the explanation for this? Thank you!!

Comment: It is OK - the `count()` method showed you that you have `2887` records and you want to process *all* of them, *not* only the first two. - So you may include the computation of the number of records in that statement: `orig_list = rdd4.take(rdd.count())` (instead of your two separate statements).

Comment: `orig_list = orig_list = rdd4.take(2)` was an (innocent) mistake - I assigned records needlessly twice. I corrected it in my answer already. (And use `rdd4.count()` instead of `2` - see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

```
.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Not near a machine with spark however

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

orig_list = rdd4.take(2)

result = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[item] * count for item, count in orig_list_item]))
          for orig_list_item in orig_list]
```

The output of `print result`:

```
[['11394071', '11052103', '11052101'],  
 ['11847272', '11847272', '999999', '11847272', '11847272', '11847272']]
```

---

**The explanation:**

It is so called (a bit complex) *list comprehension* - read it from the right:

```
for orig_list_item in orig_list
```

It is clear, isn't it? With every `orig_list_item` (which is itself a list) in your `orig_list` we will do the same thing:

```
for item, count in orig_list_item
```

We will unpack individual parts of every pair in it (giving them the names `item` and `count`, respectively - for example for the very first pair it will be `item == u'11394071'`, `count == 1`).

Now we create the list of this item

```
[item]
```

and will repeat it `count` times

```
[item] * count
```

Unfortunately, we will obtain a list of list, something as (from your second, more interesting sub-list)

```
[['11847272', '11847272'], ['999999'], ['11847272', '11847272', '11847272']]
```

so we need combine them (concatenate) into a *simple* list - the function (class method) of the imported modulus `itertools`

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable()
```

will make it for us.

But - unfortunately again - this function in higher versions of `Python` (I think from `Python 2.7`) produces a *generator*, not a *list* - so we will use finally the built-in function `list()` to obtain the desirable list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function and preserving the RDD:

```
def explode_list(data):
    inner_result = []
    for item, count in data:
        inner_result.append([item] * count)
    flatten_result = [xx for yy in inner_result for xx in yy]
    return flatten_result
```